# .htaccess rule for conditional php short_tags

Tags: .htaccess

I am allowing php short tags in the .htaccess file by using:

```
php_flag short_open_tag on
```

I would like to make this conditional, ie, when the param `st0` is in the URL then `short_tag off` else `short_tag on`

What is the .htaccess rule to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to understand that this is *not entirely* possible in `.htaccess` as `php_flag` directive is unconditional.

Here is **work around solution** to make it work:

**Step 1:** In your root .htaccess have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)st0= [NC]
RewriteRule !^_st0\.php/ _st0.php%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

<Files _st0.php>
   php_flag short_open_tag on
</Files>
```

**Step 2:** Create a file called `_st0.php` in `DocumentRoot`:

```
<?php include substr($_SERVER["PATH_INFO"], 1); ?>
```

Here is how it works:

1. `mod_rewrite` will rewrite every request with `st0` parameter to `/_st0.php`.
2. `<Files _st0.php>` directive will conditionally turn on `short_open_tag` ONLY for file `/_st0.php`.
3. `/_st0.php` will just forward the request to your actual request URI thus **enabling `short_open_tag` for your case of URL with parameter `st0` only**.

Comment: OK - I've not tested this yet - but it's a clever solution. I'll let you know once I've tested.